# png белый фон html

Tags: html, png

Убираю фон в картинке на прозрачный. сохраняю картинку в формате png, но при отображении на странице все равно в местах где фона не было появляется белый фон. в чем дело? использую bootstrap 3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <div id="headerwrap" id="home" name="home">
        <header class="clearfix">
                <h1>
                    <a class="center-block" href="#home"><img src="assets/img/btn.png"></a>
                </h1>
        </header>       
        </div>
        .center-block {
            display: block;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как по картинке можно что-то понять? Добавьте код, картинку

Comment: картинку нормальным редактором сохрани в .png) прозрачности значит нет

Comment: @Elena, добавил и код и картинку

Comment: вы пробовали обновить страницу без кэширования? может просто вы сначала подключали изображение в формате jpg, а потом поменяли на png и сейчас выводится старая картинка(jpg)

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich, да, обновляю каждый раз с очисткой кеша и аппаратной перезагрузкой.

Comment: @Elena, сохранял в фотошопе

Comment: а у класса center-block случайно фон белый не прописан в css?

Comment: Картинка нормальная это у ссылки скорее-всего фон задан

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich, добавил код стиля `.center-block`

Comment: а можете попробовать открыть эту страницу в браузере, которым ещё её не открывали? Очень интересно что будет

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirovich, открыл в IE картина таже

Comment: @АнтонБурак, проверьте чтобы у самой картинки в стилях не был задан фон, в стилях по-умолчанию или где-то в плагинах! Потому как в примере все отлично работает (см. ответ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все в порядке:

```css
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#headerwrap {
  background: #000;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerwrap" name="home">
  <header class="clearfix">
    <h1>
      <a class="center-block" href="#home">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/njxtw.png">
      </a>
    </h1>
  </header>       
</div>
```

Возможно у ссылки где-то по-умолчанию еще заданы стили и задан белый фон, либо у самой картинки задан фон.

Кстати у `<div id="headerwrap" id="home" name="home">` может быть только один `id`

Comment: Спасибо, сам просто тупанул. был стиль в глубине css
`a img {
    background: white;
}`
всем большое спасибо.